# Why is not ClientID not evaluating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this inside a usercontrol in my aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" onkeydown="textCounterLatest('<%=txtContent.ClientID%>' , '<%=remLen.ClientID %>', 500);"
                onkeyup="textCounterLatest( '<%=txtContent.ClientID%>' , '<%=remLen.ClientID %>', 500);" ID="txtContent" MaxLength="500"
                runat="server" Height="85px" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

But this clientID isn't evaluating. Instead the HTML generated is:

```
<textarea style="height:85px;width:100%;" onkeyup="textCounterLatest( '&lt;%=txtContent.ClientID%&gt;' , '&lt;%=remLen.ClientID %&gt;', 500);" onkeydown="textCounterLatest('&lt;%=txtContent.ClientID%&gt;' , '&lt;%=remLen.ClientID %&gt;', 500);" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2_ctl02_ucTaxAnswer_txtContent" cols="20" rows="2" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2$ctl02$ucTaxAnswer$txtContent"></textarea>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" onkeydown='<%= "textCounterLatest(\"" + txtContent.ClientID + "\", \"" + remLen.ClientID + "\")" %>'                 ID="txtContent" MaxLength="500" runat="server" Height="85px" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You are funny. If I could do that, I would have done that. I have many usercontrols and this control is inside that control.

Comment: You would have to add jquery and attach these javascript events

Comment: Hmm this is my last resort. I am trying that only now.

Comment: Can you remove -1 vote as I answered based on the information you provided

Comment: Sure. But it says my vote is locked. Can you please edit the answer. May be put a . at the end. Then I will be able to vote.

Comment: Can you also try onkeydown='<%= "textCounterLatest(\"" + txtContent.ClientID + "\", \"" + remLen.ClientID + "\")" %>'

Comment: @fenis: You solved the issue! Your comment works. Please edit the answer. I would like to vote you and tick.

Answer (score 1):

since you are already in an ASP.NET code block it is escaping the XML. since you are in a code block just do normal string concatenation and you should be fine:

```
onkeyup="textCounterLatest( '<%=txtContent.ClientID%>' , '<%=remLen.ClientID %>', 500);"
```

to

```
onkeyup="textCounterLatest('" + txtContent.ClientID + "' , '" + remLen.ClientID + "', 500);"
```

Comment: sorry my bad my web forms is apparently a little rusty, i have posted a new response

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't evaluated because it's inside a text literal in your markup.

My first choice for a work-around is the "static" ClientIDMode. Failing that (say, inside a databound item or in older code), I would have a javascript object in the header devoted mainly to clientIDs, and reference that everywhere in my html/javascript markup.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in true webforms fashion in the code behind:

```
txtContent.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", string.Format("textCounterLatest('{0}' , '{1}', 500);", txtContent.ClientID, remLen.ClientID));
```

I'll admit its extremely awkward in comparison to any other web development language but welcome to webforms!